# How do I reset my Web2Py application?

Tags: web2py

I deleted all the directories in my Web2Py application except the controllers, models, views and static in an attempt to reset my app, since I had made some changes to my database structure and thought migrations would be too much trouble to take for a new app with a near-empty database.

Now I'm getting an error in the console saying that web2py can't open the database file. The web interface gives me an unknown ticket.

Here's the message from the console:

```
DEBUG: connect attempt 4, connection error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 4736, in __init__
    self._adapter = ADAPTERS[self._dbname](*args)   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 1655, in __init__
    self.pool_connection(connect)   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 444, in pool_connection

    self.connection = f()   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 1654, in connect
    return self.driver.Connection(dbpath, **driver_args) OperationalError: unable to open database file ERROR:web2py:Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 204, in restrict ed
    exec ccode in environment   File "E:/Programming/Python/web2py/applications/vote_up\compiled\models\db.py" , line 14, in <module>   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 4749, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError, "Failure to connect, tried %d times:\n%s" % (attempts, t b) RuntimeError: Failure to connect, tried 5 times: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 4736, in __init__
    self._adapter = ADAPTERS[self._dbname](*args)   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 1655, in __init__
    self.pool_connection(connect)   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 444, in pool_connection

    self.connection = f()   File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 1654, in connect
    return self.driver.Connection(dbpath, **driver_args) OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/sathvikp/AppADay/tree/master/vote_up).

How can I make Web2Py look at it as a fresh app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do the following

1. Create a new app, using the admin interface.
2. Copy my controllers, models, views and static files to the new application.

Comment: Thanks @David, that is what I ended up doing...
But perhaps there is a better way to do the same, since we have to rename our app each time we do this.
Also it'd be nice to know of another way to change the database structure than reseting the app.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything to change the database structure other than changing your model.  Migrations are automatic.  If you want to avoid [migrations](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/6#Migrations), you can just clear your database directory (if you are using sqlite) and web2py will create the database from scratch.

Comment: Well, I had renamed a field in a table but when I tried to access it, I get an error saying that there is no such field... Also deleting the directories is what gave me that error with an unknown ticket, I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Sathvik it should be ok to delete **just** the **contents** of the databases directory.  Then web2py will create the an empty database from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, that did the job. I guess web2py doesn't check/create those directories after the first time.
Thanks for your help :)

I still wonder why it failed to recognize the renamed field...

Comment: Just found out I had compiled the app, so it was still using the older model back then :)

Comment: please update your answer so that it could help others in the future. Thanks